# Computation of the density of the ratio of two random variables

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, computational-statistics, nonparametric-density

**Background:**

For two continuous random variables, $X$ and $Y$, the density of $Z := \frac{X}{Y}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
    p_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert y\rvert\, p_{XY}(zy, y) \, \text{d}y,
\end{equation}
where $p_{XY}(x, y)$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ (see [ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation) and [joint density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Continuous_case)).

**Question:**

My question is about the computation of this density:

How can I compute $p_Z(z_i)$ if I am given values of the joint density at discrete points, $p_{XY}(x_i, y_i)$?

**Additional thoughts:**

Let's say, for simplicity, that the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are equally spaced and take on the same values. That is $x_i = y_i = a_{\text{min}} + ih$ (for some minimum value $a_\text{min}$) and we store the joint density in a matrix $M^{XY}$, where $M^{XY}_{ij} = p_{XY}(x_i, y_i)$.

If I wanted to compute, say, $p_Z(1)$, then I have

\begin{equation}
    p_Z(1) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert y\rvert\, p_{XY}(y, y) \, \text{d}y,
\end{equation}
so I would use the leading diagonal of the matrix (i.e. where $x=y$) to get $p_{XY}(y_i, y_i)$ and then integrate using some numerical scheme. But what if I want to compute other values, say $p_Z(0.8)$ or $p_Z(1.5)$? Now it is not clear to me.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not know the joint density in its entirety, you cannot compute the integral.

Comment: @Xi'an Could you explain why? I want to approximate the integral using a numerical method. I have shown it is possible to do this when $z=1$, why would it not be possible in other cases? Perhaps you could make it an answer?

Comment: What do you know about the distributions of $X$ and $Y?$

Comment: @BruceET I am assuming $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous.